# Запятая перед "известное как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Не могу понять, нужна ли запятая перед `известное как`.

*Из всех, самым ужасным было наводнение(,) известное как "Всемирный потоп".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Из всех* [наводнений] *самым ужасным было наводнение, **известное как Всемирный потоп.***

**А.** Первая запятая не нужна — некоторая пауза при чтении возникает из-за того, что пропущено слово "наводнений" (во избежание повтора).

**Б.** Вторая запятая необходима — она отделяет согласованное определение "известное как Всемирный потоп" (прилагательное с зависимыми словами), стоящее после определяемого слова "наводнение" (какое?).
[Правило](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_174#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5,%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83.):
**1.** Обособляется согласованное определение, состоящее из нескольких слов и относящееся к предшествующему имени существительному.

В это время толпы туристов осаждают аббатство, **известное как Монт-Сан-Мишель**. [Дарья Глебова. Бретань: дыхание Земноморья // «Homes & Gardens», 2004.04.30]

**В.** *Всемирный потоп* брать в кавычки нет необходимости — сочетание используется в прямом значении.

Катастрофа, о которой наверняка знают все,  ― **Всемирный потоп**. [А. М. Городницкий. Тайны и мифы науки. В поисках истины (2014)]

**Г.** Предложение можно написать и так:
*Самым ужасным из всех было наводнение, известное как Всемирный потоп.*